# Freeing memory in std::vector

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-management, memory-leaks

I've an abstract class called GameState which looks like this,

```
#ifndef GAMESTATE_H
#define GAMESTATE_H

#include <iostream>

class GameState
{
public:
    virtual ~GameState(void) = 0 { std::cout << "~GameState" << std::endl; };

    virtual void init     (void) = 0;
    virtual void update   (void) = 0;
    virtual void shutdown (void) = 0;

private:

};

#endif
```

In main.cpp,

```
// Lv1Stage and Lv2Stage is derived class from GameState class.
GameState* lv1Stage = new Lv1Stage
GameState* lv2Stage = new Lv2Stage

// This adds states to state vector which is in gameStateManager.
gameStateManager.addState(lv1Stage);
gameStateManager.addState(lv2Stage);



while(gameStateManager.getType() != ST_QUIT)
    {
        gameStateManager.update();
    }
```

When I quit the game(when I get out of the loop), I gotta release memories that I allocated to GameState. So I made a function in GameStateManager, called clean, which looks like this.

```
void GameStateManager::clean(void)
{   
    while (!_states.empty())
    {
         //first, release all memories of each states.
        _states.back()->shutdown();
         //and then, clear memory of state..
        _states.pop_back();
    }

    _states.clear();

}
```

The reason that I made this clean function is, I don't want to delete all of game states I add every single time, like,

```
delete lv1Stage;
delete lv2Stage;
delete lv3Stage;
...
```

So I put clean() function in destructor of gameStateManager, but it seems not working since I detected memory leak.

But the thing is, when I delete all the states myself like above code, memory leak is not detected. However, it causes unhandled exception (my guess is because _states is null cuz I deleted it manually).

So, in conclusion,
- I used clean function to de-allocate memories of vector components(which is game states) in destructor.

- But it seems not working (memory leak)
- However, deleting all memories myself is bothering me.

Can you guys give me some solutions or, what am I missing?

Comment: `GameState* lv1Stage = new Lv1Stage GameState* lv2Stage = new Lv2Stage` is not valid C++. If `_states` is a `std::vector<GameState*>` then you also need to `delete _states.back();`. Consider using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameState>>` instead, and having `~GameState()` implicitly destroy its own resources. Then you can free all of your resources with a single call to `_states.clear();`.

Comment: [See this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/437014b8b6e851d6).  Note that the call to `states.clear()` is superfluous because the vector and its contents are automatically destroyed when it goes out of scope. The important thing to note here is that `std::unique_ptr` will automatically `delete` its contents for you when it is destroyed (via `states.clear();` in this case).

Comment: Is `_states` a vector of pointers? If so, you never deleted those pointers

Comment: Since this is clearly a beginners question: The need to call `delete` has nothing to do with `vector`. `vector` manages its own memory. The need for `delete` comes from the use of `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `vector` holds `GameState*` pointers to objects  that are allocated with `new`. They *must* be freed with `delete`.  So, you need to add that, eg:

```
_states.back()->shutdown();
delete _states.back(); // <-- add this!
_states.pop_back();
```

If you are using C++11 or later, you can change your `vector` to hold `std::unique_ptr<GameState>` objects instead of raw `GameState*` pointers, and then `delete` will be called automatically for you when you remove  objects from the vector.